# display input at another page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```html
<h1>User Review</h1>
<p><em style="font-weight:bold">Still not convinced? </em><br><br> Well let's take a look and see what our </p>
<p>users have to say about RedPanda.</p>
<nav><h1 id="r1" id="comment"> Amazing   <br id='rating_1'><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></h1></nav>
<nav><h1 id="r1">Brilliant    <br><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></h1></nav>
<nav><h1 id="r1">Good       <br><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span></h1></nav>
<nav><h1 id="r1">Ugly Logo       <br><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span></h1></nav>
<nav><h1 id="r1">Free Software      <br><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span></h1></nav><br>
<a href="redpanda.html" id="reviewlink">You can write your review here :)</a>
```

Above is the user review html page

```html
    <form action="userreview.html" onsubmit="tosubmit()">


<div style="padding-bottom: 18px;">First Name:<span style="color: red;"> </span><br/>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
<div style="padding-bottom: 18px;">Last Name:<span style="color: red;"> </span><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<br>
<div style="padding-bottom: 18px;">Review:<span style="color: red;"> </span><br/>
<textarea id="data_8" ${readonly} name="data_8" style="width : 450px;" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
<nav>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">★★★★★</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">★★★★</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">★★★</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">★★</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">★</label>
</fieldset>
</nav>  
 <div style="padding-bottom: 18px;">Would you recommend this product?<span style="color: red;"> *</span><br/>
<span><input type="radio" id="data_9_0" name="data_9" value="Yes"/> Yes</span><br/>
<span><input type="radio" id="data_9_1" name="data_9" value="No"/> No</span><br/>
<span><input type="radio" id="data_9_2" name="data_9" value="I am not sure"/> I am not sure</span><br/>
</br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

This is the form page where users put in their review and their rating. I want the input to replace one of the reviews that i had put on my html at the user review page. Can someone help me ??? thanks

(for example when i put my opinion on this form page, then when i submit the opinion i put will be appear as one of the review on the user review page)

I totally have no idea how to start this so it will be good if some suggestion is given to me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is making a database to hold all the reviews. Then you can use php to make the entries in the database and to show all the reviews in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am sort of confused by what you want but I am guessing that you have that user review form that you want to put on a page. You have multiple ways to do that. My personal favorite is doing it in PHP but there are other ways as well.

HTML:

```
 <div w3-include-html="userreview.html"></div>
```

PHP:

```
include_once 'userreview.html';
```

jQuery:

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#user-review").load("userreview.html"); 
    });
</script> 
<div id="user-review"></div>
```

iFrame:

```
<iframe src="userreview.html"></iframe>
```

Any one of these should work. If this helped please click the check mark.